# JavaScript Animation- stopping internal div movement upon reaching the outer div border

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hello to all the masterminds of Stack Overflow!
As part of an assignment in school I was asked to create a simple animation using CSS and JavaScript.
 I created a large outer div and inside of it placed another smaller div, using JavaScript, I'm able to move my smaller div around the larger div by using the JS onkeypress event.
What I can't seem to do, (and this is my question) is to simply **stop** the smaller div as it reaches the bigger div's border. In my code it appears hidden after it "crosses" the outer div.
 For some reason, I can't get it to work when using the build-in snippet in this site. In WebStorm 11 it works like magic!Any advice would help, thanks in advance!

```js
< script >
  //Declare Variables
  var test = document.getElementById("test");
var object = document.getElementById("object");
var posx = 200;
var posy = 200;
var width = 100;
var height = 100;
var rotate = 0;
//On KeyDown
document.onkeydown = function keyPress(event) {
    var x = event.which;
    var speed = 5;

    switch (x) {
      case 38:
        test.innerHTML = "Up";
        posy -= speed;
        object.style.top = posy + "px";
        break;
      case 39:
        test.innerHTML = "Right";
        posx += speed;
        object.style.left = posx + "px";
        break;
      case 40:
        test.innerHTML = "Down";
        posy += speed;
        object.style.top = posy + "px";
        break;
      case 37:
        test.innerHTML = "Left";
        posx -= speed;
        object.style.left = posx + "px";
        break;
      case 90:
        width += 1;
        height += 1;
        test.innerHTML = "Z";
        object.style.width = width + "px";
        object.style.height = height + "px";
        break;
      case 88:
        test.innerHTML = "X";
        width -= 1;
        height -= 1;
        object.style.width = width + "px";
        object.style.height = height + "px";
        break;
      case 65:
        rotate += 1;
        object.style.transform = "rotate('rotate')";

    }

    < /script>
```

```css
<style> * {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#myDiv {
  background-color: #005f5f;
  width: 500px;
  min-height: 500px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
}
#object {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
  top: 200px;
  left: 200px;
  display: block;
}
</style>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Lesson #2</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Lesson #2</h1>
  <div id="myDiv">
    <div id="object">

    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="test">

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just needed to add a control statement to make sure that you aren't at the border. If it's a picture, you want to set it to HALF the width of the object that is moving in the window. Otherwise it will go outside the screen. So if you are using a 10 pixel dot, change 0 to 5 and 200 to 195, ect.

```
 < script >
  //Declare Variables
  var test = document.getElementById("test");
var object = document.getElementById("object");
var posx = 200;
var posy = 200;
var width = 100;
var height = 100;
var rotate = 0;

//On KeyDown
document.onkeydown = function keyPress(event) {
    var x = event.which;
    var speed = 5;

    switch (x) {
      case 38:
      if(posy > 0){
        test.innerHTML = "Up";      
        posy -= speed;
        object.style.top = posy + "px";
        }
        break;
      case 39:
      if(posx < 200){
        test.innerHTML = "Right";
        posx += speed;
        object.style.left = posx + "px";
        }
        break;
      case 40:
      if(posy < 200){
        test.innerHTML = "Down";
        posy += speed;
        object.style.top = posy + "px";
        }
        break;
      case 37:
      if(posx > 0){
        test.innerHTML = "Left";
        posx -= speed;
        object.style.left = posx + "px";
        }
        break;
      case 90:
        width += 1;
        height += 1;
        test.innerHTML = "Z";
        object.style.width = width + "px";
        object.style.height = height + "px";
        break;
      case 88:
        test.innerHTML = "X";
        width -= 1;
        height -= 1;
        object.style.width = width + "px";
        object.style.height = height + "px";
        break;
      case 65:
        rotate += 1;
        object.style.transform = "rotate('rotate')";

    }

    < /script>
```